# How to remove a row from datagridview and reset a particular column (vb.net 2005)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2005, delete-row

I am using VS 2005 edition. I am developing a winform desktop application. Let's say I have a unbound datagridview, with table like below:

Original datagrid before delete:

[image: original datagrid before delete]

If I removed Stuff D (Item No 5), the "Item No" column supposed to reset itself accordingly. The expected output should be:

After delete row:

[image: after delete row]

The "Item No" column is not an autonumber, it's just the number I assigned incrementally as the user add in a new row(new Stuff). I tried using the following code in rowremoved event but failed to achieve the expected output. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is just showing the record index in cell, then you don't need to assign a value to cell and it's enough to set `e.Value = e.RowIndex + 1` in `CellFormatting` event.

But based on your comment it seems you need those cells have values as well. So you need to handle `RowsRemoved` and `RowsAdded` event of `DataGridView` and refresh the cell value with row number:

```
Public Sub RefreshRowNumbers(g As DataGridView)
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In g.Rows
        r.Cells(1).Value = r.Index + 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsRemoved(sender As Object, _
    e As DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsRemoved
    RefreshRowNumbers(DirectCast(sender, DataGridView))
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsAdded(sender As Object, _
    e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded
    RefreshRowNumbers(DirectCast(sender, DataGridView))
End Sub
```

Comment: There are reasons as of why I have to assign the values to the cell. the datagrid is just for display for user to view what they've already added.

Comment: OK, since you need values, you need to handle `RowsRemoved` and `RowsAdded` events and refresh row numbers. If for any reason you want to exclude the last row (new row) you can simply use a for loop instead of exclude the row if `row.IsNewRow=True`.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer or if you have any problem applying the solution.

Comment: I got exactly the result I needed. Thank you so much. I do agree, it's better to assign row index value instead of assigning it manually.